# question mark in url when make login

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i make a log in form

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Form1"><strong>Admin</strong></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Form2"><strong>Librarian</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="Form1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adminUserName" placeholder="UserName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="adminPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg " id="admin-login">Log In</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

and this is the ajax request for log in

```
$("#admin-login").click(function(){

    var data = {"username": $("#adminUserName").val(), "password": $("#adminPassword").val()};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/admin/login",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function (data) {
            if(data.success)
            {
                window.location= "/admin.html";
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data.message)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

the log in work successfully , and i'm sure that the ajax request done but sometimes when i click login button , question mark appear in url and it's seem that the page just refreshed , for example : the login page should take me to localhost:8080//index.html but it **sometimes** take me to localhost:8080//?
why this happen ? how can i solve this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the button type in the form is `submit`. Which is causing your from to be submitted and when form is submitted it reloads the page.

Change it to `button` like

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg " id="admin-login">Log In</button>
```

Or you can also prevent the default submit behavior for the form with `js` like

```
var form = document.querySelector("form");;

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
   event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: its work now , thank you , can you pleases explain what happens exactly when type was submit ??

Comment: I've already added an explanation. See the first line of answer